# How to recursively parse a formatted text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am building a webpage and instead of copying and pasting a navigation bar, I wanted to just need to copy a div and script tag and have javascript finish it for me. I have that part nearly complete but I have ran into problems when attempting to have it parse subdropdowns.

Here is my txt file containing the formatting data:

```
"Home" ==> "/";
"About" ==> "/about";

DROPDOWN [format=STD,header="Example Dropdown"] {

    "Introduction" ==> "/example/Introduction",

    DROPDOWN [format=STD,header="Sub Dropdown"] {

        "Overview" ==> "/example/overview",
        "Another item" ==> "/example/anotheritem"

    }

}
```

I have managed to get everything up until the sub-dropdowns, as I don't know how I would write that recursive code, being the main dropdown has to appended to a div, whereas the sub dropdowns must be appended to a first. I know I'll need global variables and a function, but I have not quite figured it out yet, and need advice.

Here is my CSS(referenced along with the script in the HTML file):

```
body  {

  margin: 0;
  background-color: azure;

}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #076341;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

And here is my JavaScript (not finished yet, and a rewrite over my original (updated), so this does not have any dropdown code):

```
document.body.onload = function() {

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/testdata.txt', true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {

            var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

            if (type.indexOf("text") !== 1) {

                get_data(request.responseText + "");

            }

        }

    }

}

function get_data(file_data) {

    file_data = file_data.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');

    file_data = file_data.replace(/([^"]+)|("[^"]+")/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
        if ($1) {
            return $1.replace(/\s/g, '');
        } else {
            return $2; 
        } 
    });

    var navdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    navdiv.className = "topnav";
    navdiv.id = "topnavmenu";

    var pieces1 = file_data.split(";");

    var isBetween = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < pieces1.length; i++) {

        if (pieces1[i].indexOf("DROPDOWN") > -1) {

            // Do something, with a recursive fallback option

        } else if (pieces1[i].indexOf("==>") > -1 && !isBetween) {

            var name = pieces1[i].split("==>")[0];
            var link = pieces1[i].split("==>")[1];

            name = name.substring(name.indexOf("\"") + 1, name.lastIndexOf("\""));
            link = link.substring(link.indexOf("\"") + 1, link.lastIndexOf("\""));

            var link_el = build_link(name, link);

            if (link == window.location.pathname) {

                link_el.className += ", active";

            }

            navdiv.appendChild(link_el);

        };

    }
    document.getElementById('menucontainer').appendChild(navdiv);

}

function build_link(name, dest) {

    var link = document.createElement("A");
    link.innerHTML = name;
    link.href = dest;

    return link;

}
```

Is this possible to achive? And if so, what route should I take?

By the way, I need pure Javascript only, nothing like JQuery

Comment: Are you stuck with that format or would using eg JSON make thinks a bit easier?

Comment: I could use JSON. I don't know how to use it (like, with a library) with JavaScript, but I could learn. The current format is my own.

Comment: Hi, I don’t understand why you mention a library. I was just thinking of pure JS and JSON.

Comment: My bad. For some reason, I was thinking JavaScript needed a library to parse JSON files. Sorry about that. I did end up finding a solution, however, and will be updating this question to include the solution so it may help others. Thank you for your help, though. Although I am still curious what your solution would have been with JSON, if you don't mind. Who knows? I might be able to merge our solutions into a more effective one.